# Не работает отправка формы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, email, sendmail

Здравствуйте, почему-то не работает отправка формы на почты, помогите разобраться в чем дело

```js
$("#callback-form").submit(function() { //Change
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php", //Change
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert("все работает");
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Done Functions
      th.trigger("reset");
    }, 1000);
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="callback-form">
  <h2>Оставьте свой номер и мы Вам перезвоним!</h2>
  <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
  <input class="textbox" type="hidden" name="project_name" value="MyLending">
  <input class="textbox" type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="147qq147@i.ua">
  <input class="textbox" type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Новая заявка">
  <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Введите имя" required>
  <br>
  <input class="textbox" type="tel" name="Phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона" required>
  <br>
  <button class="form-button">Перезвоните мне</button>

</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

И вот php-код, который должен отправлять данные на почту

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ($method === 'POST') {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject") {
            $message .= "
            " . (($c = !$c) ? '<tr>' : '<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">') . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ($method === 'GET') {
    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject") {
            $message .= "
            " . (($c = !$c) ? '<tr>' : '<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">') . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text)
{
    return '=?UTF-8?B?' . Base64_encode($text) . '?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL . 'From: ' . adopt($project_name) . ' <' . $admin_email . '>' . PHP_EOL . 'Reply-To: ' . $admin_email . '' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Сдается мне не пашет php код. так как в песочнице html и js отрабатывают

Answer (score 0):

У вас на кнопку отправки не повешено событие `submit`.
Добавьте

```
<button type="submit" class="form-button">Перезвоните мне</button>
```